# How to make inline-block span inherit all text-decoration of all its ancestors?

Tags: css

I have made a inline-block span inside a tag `u` and a tag `s`, hoping it being displayed with both strike and undeline text-decorations, but none of them happened.

If I set its `text-decoration` to `inherit`, it will only inherit the text-decoration of its parent, without that of its other ancestors.

How to achieve this goal: while keep it as inline-block, it should inherit the text-decorations of all its ancestors.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<u>
  <s>
    yes <span>man</span> no
  </s>
</u>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```css
u s span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline line-through;
}
```

```html
<u><s>yes <span>man</span> no</s></u>
```

You can set the `text-decoration` with `underline` and `line-through` for the `<span>` element to get the same text-decoration caused by the nested `<u>` and `<s>` elements. Using `text-decoration: inherits;` only inherits the text-decoration of the parent element (here `<s>`).

You can use the following CSS to cover different combinations of the tags:

```css
.editor-container u s span, 
.editor-container s u span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline line-through;
}
.editor-container u span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.editor-container s span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor-container">
  <u><s>yes <span>man</span> no</s></u>
  <s><u>yes <span>man</span> no</u></s>
  <u>yes <span>man</span> no</u>
  <s>yes <span>man</span> no</s>
  
  <!-- you can also use b, strong, i without additional CSS -->
  <b><s>yes <span>man</span> no</s></b>
  <s><b>yes <span>man</span> no</b></s>
  <strong><s>yes <span>man</span> no</s></strong>
  <s><strong>yes <span>man</span> no</strong></s>
  <i><s>yes <span>man</span> no</s></i>
</div>
```

You can also set the `<span>` of the editor to `display: inline;` instead of defining all these special rules:

```css
.editor-container span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor-container">
  <u><s>yes <span>man</span> no</s></u>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't add the required CSS explicitly. It automatically hampers the reason for which the question was asked.

Comment: @Sebastian Brosch I am currently using this method as a workaround, but it is not extensible. Will there be more styles, the css should be modified to maintain all the cases of these combinations.

Comment: setting the span to inline would result in wrapping it without treating it as a whole box.